# Download cloudtrail event

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I need some advise in one of my usecase regarding Cloudtrail and Python boto3.

I have some cloudtrail events like configured and i need to send the report of all those events manually by downloading the file of events.

I am planning to automate this stuff using python boto3. Can you please advise how can i use boto3 to get the cloudtrail events for some specific date i should paas at runtime along with the csv or json files downloaded and sent over the email. As of now i have created a python script which shows the cloudtrail event but not able to download the files. Please advise

Comment: Are the events you can show somehow different from the files that you want to download? In other words, if you can show them, then you can write them to a file on your own, right?

Comment: No ... The files contains event related information itself.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions is to simply configure the **deliver of those events** to an **S3 bucket**, and you have there the file of events. This configuration is part of your trail configuration and doesn't need boto3.

You can then **access events files stored on S3** using boto3 (personally the best way to interact with AWS resources), and manipulate those files as you prefer.

Comment: Make sense.... Thanks for the advise. Let me think on implementing this method.

Comment: @KapilKaushal let me know if this helped ;)

Comment: I have think of this approach. However , i need to understand once the events file are stored on S3 bucket then how can i send those files over the email automatically. As the team is not having AWS access and cannot able to login to console to view the S3 bucket. They only require the event files for analysis. Please advise.

Comment: @KapilKaushal the ansewr is "it depends". First of all, depends on file size. How large are they? Then depends on which email provider you will use. Are you planning to use Amazon SES? The max email size is then 10MB. Generally, when you want to deliver larga files by email, you give them a link so that they can download autonomously. I highly recommend to put the files behind authentication, but if our users won't have access to S3, then you need to set up a custom servire where to serve those files from.

Comment: second option (THAT I DON'T RECOMMEND) is to open files to anyone, but use a long, strong randomic file name for your files. This basically means that only who has the URL can get those files. This means that if anyone gets that URL, he will be able to download the file too, with no restrictions. This is why my previous proposal is what you should prefer.